# how to parse array of jsons in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json:

> [{"date":"2018-04-09","count":8},{"date":"2018-04-10","count":3},{"date":"2018-04-12","count":4},{"date":"2018-04-13","count":11},{"date":"2018-04-14","count":1},{"date":"2018-04-15","count":4},{"date":"2018-04-16","count":8},{"date":"2018-04-17","count":34}]

How to parse this with JSON.parse()?

I tried with JSON.parse(response);
also in this way:

```
               for(var x = 0; x < response.length; x++){
                 var stat = JSON.parse(response[x]);
               }
```

but it does not work in both ways.

the response object is the JSON above which is array!

here is the error in both cases:

> VM96:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.ajaxsuccess [as success] (login:40)
>       at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: What is `response`? Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Then why `response[x]` if `response` is a string?

Comment: You want date or count in the stat variable ?

Comment: I want string in this variable

Comment: What does _"but it does not work in both ways"_ mean? Please post any errors, or even better a [mcve].

Comment: @dimilalabar the JSON string you posted is valid: https://jsfiddle.net/e5whc0p1/ so it's unclear where your problem is based on just what you posted

Comment: And with that error we have the answer: `response` is not [JSON](http://json.org) anymore but already parsed into an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your above argument is a string -

```
response = "[{"date":"2018-04-09","count":8},{"date":"2018-04-10","count":3},{"date":"2018-04-12","count":4},{"date":"2018-04-13","count":11},{"date":"2018-04-14","count":1},{"date":"2018-04-15","count":4},{"date":"2018-04-16","count":8},{"date":"2018-04-17","count":34}]"
```

parse first then go through each entry-

```
for(var x = 0; x < response.length; x++){
  var stat = response[x];
  //stat = {"date":"2018-04-09","count":8}
}
```

But make sure `response` is what is assumed. You might be referring to `response.body` or some derivation.

Comment: That won't work though, you should use `'` and not `"` to enclose (not sure this is the correct term) the response string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming response is the json you posted

You can do

```
response = JSON.parse(response)
for (let x of response) {
    console.log(x.date) // If you want the date property
    console.log(x.count) // If you want the count property
}
```

As a side note, if you do

`var stat = x`

Like in your example, it will overide the stat variable and you'll only get the value for the last iteration. So you should use an array

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/epo4f5rb/1/

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() expects a string as input and returns a Javascript Object.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: It can help to provide an example when you explain a concept. - Cheers